# How to position Android button on top of a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I need to create the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|     |                                            |
|     |                                            |
----------------------------------------------------
   |                       |
   ImageButton             TextView
```

The ImageButton has an image and needs to scaled to fit the height of the TextView...

I've managed to position the button using a RelativeLayout:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tense_textview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tense"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
                android:background="@drawable/pause_button_background"
                android:src="@drawable/pause"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

However, this gives me:

```
                           TextView
                           |
----------------------------------------------------  
|         |                                        |
|         |                                        |
|         |-----------------------------------------
|         |                                        |
----------------------------------------------------
     |                     |
     ImageButton           RelativeLayout
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply, don't use the ImageView. use a **compound drawable** inside the TextView. By the way, you can also get rid of the useless RelativeLayout, by doing so. Therefore, write in your TextView: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pause"`

Comment: That doesn't take care of scaling of the image though...

Comment: The TextView height will be scaled to fit the ImageView's height, if set to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ImageView instead of ImageButton and add
`android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tense_textview"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/tense_textview"
android:scaleType="CENTER_CROP OR CENTER_INSIDE "`

CENTER_CROP = Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

CENTER_INSIDE = Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

From personal experience I never use ImageButton because ImageView gives me more flexibility and there is inherent padding in the ImageButton that prevented me from achieving pixel perfection. (It was do-able just a big pain)

Comment: So for the textview do you want it to be centered to the right of the imagebutton? Meaning with the remaining space you're centering the text vertically and horizontally?

Comment: No I want the text to ignore the button, so that it centers within the parent

Comment: This doesn't scale the button, it centres the button and the textview vertically

Comment: What do you mean by scaling the button? If you want the button to take up more space then you can remove the margin. And if you only want the text to center horizontally I'll make a small edit to the textview.

Comment: Make the button the same height as the textview (not the other way around), also make sure the width of the button scales to match it's new height...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add properties:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tense_textview"
```

and

`android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tense_textview"`
to your imageview

Comment: Yes for this you can add android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE" with above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set height of the ImageButton to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tense_textview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/tense"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pauseButton"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pauseButton"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pauseButton"/>
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
      android:background="@drawable/pause_button_background"
      android:src="@drawable/pause"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```